# Compound time and tempo indication in quarter note

Tags: notation, time-signatures, tempo

I am studying a piece, the time signature is 12/8.

The tempo indication is "Allegretto, (quarter_note) = 76". I am a bit baffled, as I expected a **dotted** quarter note.

Is this a typo? Or is this accepted notation? And if the latter: should I set my metronome to 76 or, uhhh, a third slower (50)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! If you haven't already, please [take the tour](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour) and [visit the help centre](https://music.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would expect a dotted quarter beat.  If it's a printed copy from an established publisher, I'd say it's a misprint.  If a computer-printed score from an amateur, I'd suspect ignorance!

But 50bpm is too slow for alegretto.  It's a misprint.

Comment: Why questioners accept answers but don't upvote is something i never understood, good answer btw.

Comment: I see "quarter note = " notation for compound meters (e.g. 12/8, 9/8) all the time in Musescore, mainly because that's the default tempo indication you can put on a score.

Comment: Yup.  Musescore is great for the price, but lacks many refinements.  And its users are often inexperienced.